# Get correct http request response without selenium?

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to access data from this site:

```
URL = ('https://www.optionsxpress.com.au/'
       'OXNetTools/Chains/index.aspx?Chai'
       'nType=3&SessionID=C73763A1C9E747C'
       'DBDB18D0276D6B780')
```

The data is separated by calls and puts, accessed by a radio button. I've tried supplying the form data with requests like this:

```
data='{"args":{"symbol":"SPY","range":"4","exp":"3/20/2015;1","currentimpvol":"14.08","stockpricedisplay":"205.83","daystillexp":"27","interestrate":"1.00","txtPricerDividendDate":"12/19/2014","txtPricerDividend":"1.13","lstPricerDivFreq":"91","includediv":"false","isdetached":"0","callput":"P","sessionid":"C73763A1C9E747CDBDB18D0276D6B780"}}'


r = requests.get(URL, params=data, allow_redirects=False)
```

but it only returns the calls, e.g., the default url/response.

I've been able to use selenium's webdriver to do this, but I want to know how to do it without selenium, ideally using urllib2 and the standard library.

Comment: If you're passing the GET arguments via parameters, you probably shouldn't have them in the URL as well... not sure it makes a difference for your issue though. When you were using Selenium, were you actually pressing the buttons on the form? There's a good chance you'll need to collect some cookies and get a valid session ID before this call will work.

Comment: Is there a way to pass along post data wirhout passing to url? Becuae the url is the same for the calls and puts. Yes, with selenium i was clicking the button ina firefox browser, which i want to avoid

Comment: POST data isn't passed via the URL, only GET parameters. You'll need to look at the form's HTML to determine what method to use.

You'll probably have some reverse engineering to do if you're trying to avoid pressing the buttons. Every site is different, and since this site seems to rely on sessions you're probably going to have some extra work. What I've done before is visit the target page to obtain a cookie and get any "hidden" field values, then be sure to include those cookies/values when accessing the server in subsequent calls.

Comment: How did you find the hidden values?

Comment: Open it in your browser and "view source"... I would expect there to at least be a CSRF token or something. But its going to be a challenge, I imagine the website would not appreciate your attempts and have gone out of their way to make it difficult.

Comment: OK, I managed to get the correct response by passing the 'OXAUTH=' cookie. Can I reliably pass the same value for this each time I want to parse the site, or do cookies 'refresh'/ need to be updated?

Comment: It's up to the server how long the session is valid for and what the requirements for renewing it are. The cookie itself may have an expiration - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age . If you have requests setup with a "cookie jar", and the server attempts to refresh the cookie, everything should magically work so long as you don't wait too long. Again though, this question is a bit too specific for Stack. I would say experiment and find out empirically.